# Dividing windows form using tablelayout

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayout

I am working on an application in which list of controls are added to a form and on a button click(edit) the user can drag and drop the control in runtime. I want to arrange the control dragged and dropped by the user in a table like format with columns and rows after button click, for which i created tablelayout dynamically. But the table layout seems to be creating inside the controls itself and i am not able to add tablelayout from toolbox since it blocks/hides the controls added during runtime. I use below code to create tablelayout.

```
 void fnEngageControlMover()
    {
        //Control con;        
        foreach (Control llbl in pnlShortcuts.Controls)
        {
            libs.ControlMover.createtable(llbl);
            if (llbl.Visible)
            {
                libs.ControlMover.Init(llbl, pnlShortcuts);
                if (llbl.Controls.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (Control lctx in llbl.Controls)
                    {

                        if (lctx.Name.Length > 8 && lctx.Name.Substring(0, 8) == "lpnlBtns")
                        {
                            llbl.Width = llbl.Width + lctx.Width;
                            lctx.Visible = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void createtable(Control panel)
    {
        TableLayoutPanel dynamicTableLayoutPanel = new TableLayoutPanel();
        dynamicTableLayoutPanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(26, 12);
        dynamicTableLayoutPanel.Name = "TableLayoutPanel1";
        dynamicTableLayoutPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(228, 200);
        dynamicTableLayoutPanel.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;

        // Add rows and columns
        dynamicTableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount = 3;
        dynamicTableLayoutPanel.RowCount = 5;

        dynamicTableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 30F));
        dynamicTableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 30F));
        dynamicTableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 40F));
        dynamicTableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 52F));
        dynamicTableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 44F));
        dynamicTableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 44F));
        dynamicTableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 38F));
        dynamicTableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 8F));
        panel.Controls.Add(dynamicTableLayoutPanel);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: In Designer open `Document Outline` window (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`). In that window you can change controls hierarchy, which will bring needed controls to the front or set it to the back

Comment: Moved it to back, but some controls are added dynamically and they are not displayed in the form after adding tablelayout. I want to arrange those dynamic controls hence I need tablelayout

Comment: If you want add control inside of `TableLayout` then do it: `this.YourTableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(yourControl, columnIndex, rowIndex);`

Comment: Thanks for help. But i guess i was not clear about the condition . The question is updated.

Comment: TableLayout is a container - it contains other controls. If you put controls to the columns/rows then you need add control to tableLayout columns or controls